# `NoMethodError`, even when the method is in the `instance_methods` list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, instance-methods

Using the following code, when I try to use my code at the debugger point (attempt to use 'rating' accessor from the Song class), why do I get

`NoMethodError Exception: undefined method "rating" for #<Class:0xb3b7db04>`

even though `Song.instance_methods` clearly shows that `:rating` and `:rating=` are in the list?

-

```
#songs_controller.rb
class SongsController < ApplicationController    
    def index
        debugger
        @ratings = Song.rating
    end
end
```

-

```
#schema.rb
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20111119180638) do
    create_table "songs", :force => true do |t|
        t.string   "title"
        t.string   "rating"
  end
end
```

-

```
#song.rb
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :rating
end
```

Comment: Can someone please explain why I received the -1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In below code you call `rating` on Song which is a class, that's why its throwing an error.
`Song.instance_methods` clearly shows that :rating and :rating= are in the list of Song class as a instance method. you can call that method on `Song.new` instance, but not on `Song` class.

you should call rating method like this:

```
  @rating = Song.new.rating

  Song.new.rating = "good"
```

in place of this:

```
   @ratings = Song.rating
```

Hope it will help. Thanks

Comment: Yep, that worked... with the small additions: `id = params[:id]` and `@song = Song.find(id)`

Comment: I will when I can; it doesn't allow me to do so, so quickly. :)